# Can I make a Lens with a Monad constraint?

Tags: haskell, monads, haskell-lens

**Context:** This question is specifically in reference to `Control.Lens` (version 3.9.1 at the time of this writing)

I've been using the lens library and it is very nice to be able to read and write to a piece (or pieces for traversals) of a structure. I then had a though about whether a lens could be used against an external database. Of course, I would then need to execute in the `IO Monad`.  So to generalize:

**Question:**

Given a getter, `(s -> m a)` and an setter `(b -> s -> m t)` where `m` is a Monad, is possible to construct `Lens s t a b` where the Functor of the lens is now contained to also be a Monad? Would it still be possible to compose these with `(.)` with other "purely functional" lenses?

**Example:**

Could I make `Lens (MVar a) (MVar b) a b`  using `readMVar` and `withMVar`?

**Alternative:**

Is there an equivalent to Control.Lens for containers in the `IO` monad such as `MVar` or `IORef` (or `STDIN`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been thinking about this idea for some time, which I'd call **mutable lenses**. So far, I haven't made it into a package, let me know, if you'd benefit from it.

First let's recall the generalized van Laarhoven Lenses (after some imports we'll need later):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import           Data.Functor.Constant
import           Data.Functor.Identity
import           Data.Traversable (Traversable)
import qualified Data.Traversable as T
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.STM
import           Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar

type Lens s t a b = forall f . (Functor f) => (a -> f b) -> (s -> f t)
type Lens' s a = Lens s s a a
```

we can create such a lens from a "getter" and a "setter" as

```
mkLens :: (s -> a) -> (s -> b -> t) -> Lens s t a b
mkLens g s  f x = fmap (s x) (f (g x))
```

and get a "getter"/"setter" from a lens back as

```
get :: Lens s t a b -> (s -> a)
get l = getConstant . l Constant

set :: Lens s t a b -> (s -> b -> t)
set l x v = runIdentity $ l (const $ Identity v) x
```

as an example, the following lens accesses the first element of a pair:

```
_1 :: Lens' (a, b) a
_1 = mkLens fst (\(x, y) x' -> (x', y))
-- or directly: _1 f (a,c) = (\b -> (b,c)) `fmap` f a
```

Now how a **mutable lens** should work? Getting some container's content involves a monadic action. And setting a value doesn't change the container, it remains the same, just as a mutable piece of memory does. So the result of a mutable lens will have to be monadic, and instead of the return type container `t` we'll have just `()`. Moreover, the `Functor` constraint isn't enough, since we need to interleave it with monadic computations. Therefore, we'll need `Traversable`:

```
type MutableLensM  m s  a b
    = forall f . (Traversable f) => (a -> f b) -> (s -> m (f ()))
type MutableLensM' m s  a
    = MutableLensM m s a a
```

(`Traversable` is to monadic computations what `Functor` is to pure computations).

Again, we create helper functions

```
mkLensM :: (Monad m) => (s -> m a) -> (s -> b -> m ())
        -> MutableLensM m s a b
mkLensM g s  f x = g x >>= T.mapM (s x) . f


mget :: (Monad m) => MutableLensM m s a b -> s -> m a
mget l s = liftM getConstant $ l Constant s

mset :: (Monad m) => MutableLensM m s a b -> s -> b -> m ()
mset l s v = liftM runIdentity $ l (const $ Identity v) s
```

As an example, let's create a mutable lens from a `TVar` within `STM`:

```
alterTVar :: MutableLensM' STM (TVar a) a
alterTVar = mkLensM readTVar writeTVar
```

These lenses are one-sidedly directly composable with `Lens`, for example

```
alterTVar . _1 :: MutableLensM' STM (TVar (a, b)) a
```

---

**Notes:**

- Mutable lenses could be made more powerful if we allow that the modifying function to include effects:

  ```
  type MutableLensM2  m s  a b
      = (Traversable f) => (a -> m (f b)) -> (s -> m (f ()))
  type MutableLensM2' m s  a
      = MutableLensM2 m s a a

  mkLensM2 :: (Monad m) => (s -> m a) -> (s -> b -> m ())
           -> MutableLensM2 m s a b
  mkLensM2 g s  f x = g x >>= f >>= T.mapM (s x)
  ```

  However, it has two major drawbacks:

  1. It isn't composable with pure `Lens`.
  2. Since the inner action is arbitrary, it allows you to shoot yourself in the foot by mutating this (or other) lens during the mutating operation itself.
- There are other possibilities for monadic lenses. For example, we can create a monadic copy-on-write lens that preserves the original container (just as `Lens` does), but where the operation involves some monadic action:

  ```
  type LensCOW m s t a b
      = forall f . (Traversable f) => (a -> f b) -> (s -> m (f t))
  ```
- I've made [jLens](https://github.com/ppetr/jLens) - a Java library for mutable lenses, but the API is of course far from being as nice as Haskell lenses.

Comment: Doesn't this approach require a readTVar, even if all you'd need is a writeTVar when you're setting?

Comment: Yes, that's a drawback. I'm trying to construct a different representation which avoids it.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can not constrain the "Functor of the lens" to also be a Monad. The type for a `Lens` requires that it be compatible with all `Functor`s:

```
type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

This reads in English something like: A Lens is a function, which, for all types `f` where `f` is a `Functor`, takes an `(a -> f b)` and returns an `s -> f t`. The key part of that is that it must provide such a function for every `Functor` `f`, not just some subset of them that happen to be `Monad`s.

---

**Edit:**

You could make a `Lens (MVar a) (MVar b) a b`, since none of `s` `t` `a`, or `b` are constrained. What would the types on the getter and setter needed to construct it be then? The type of the getter would be `(MVar a -> a)`, which I believe could only be implemented as `\_ -> undefined`, since there's nothing that extracts the value from an MVar except as `IO a`. The setter would be `(MVar a -> b -> MVar b)`, which we also can't define since there's nothing that makes an `MVar` except as `IO (MVar b)`.

This suggests that instead we could instead make the type `Lens (MVar a) (IO (MVar b)) (IO a) b`. This would be an interesting avenue to pursue further with some actual code and a compiler, which I don't have right now. To combine that with other "purely functional" lenses, we'd probably want some sort of lift to lift the lens into a monad, something like `liftLM :: (Monad m) => Lens s t a b -> Lens s (m t) (m a) b`.

---

**Code that compiles (2nd edit):**

In order to be able to use the `Lens s t a b` as a `Getter s a` we must have `s ~ t` and `a ~ b`. This limits our type of useful lenses lifted over some `Monad` to the widest type for `s` and `t` and the widest type for `a` and `b`. If we substitute `b ~ a` into out possible type we would have `Lens (MVar a) (IO (MVar a)) (IO a) a`, but we still need `MVar a ~ IO (MVar a)` and `IO a ~ a`. We take the wides of each of these types, and choose `Lens (IO (MVar a)) (IO (MVar a)) (IO a) (IO a)`, which Control.Lens.Lens lets us write as `Lens' (IO (MVar a)) (IO a)`. Following this line of reasoning, we can make a complete system for combining "purely functional" lenses with lenses on monadic values. The operation to lift a "purely function" lens, `liftLensM`, then has the type `(Monad m) => Lens' s a -> LensF' m s a`, where `LensF' f s a ~ Lens' (f s) (f a)`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Main (
    main
) where

import Control.Lens
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

main = do
    -- Using MVar
    putStrLn "Ordinary MVar"
    var <- newMVar 1
    output var
    swapMVar var 2
    output var

    -- Using mvarLens
    putStrLn ""
    putStrLn "MVar accessed through a LensF' IO"
    value <- (return var) ^. mvarLens
    putStrLn $ show value 
    set mvarLens (return 3) (return var)
    output var

    -- Debugging lens
    putStrLn ""
    putStrLn "MVar accessed through a LensF' IO that also debugs"
    value <- readM (debug mvarLens) var
    putStrLn $ show value 
    setM (debug mvarLens) 4 var
    output var 

    -- Debugging crazy box lens
    putStrLn ""
    putStrLn "MVar accessed through a LensF' IO that also debugs through a Box that's been lifted to LensF' IO that also debugs"
    value <- readM ((debug mvarLens) . (debug (liftLensM boxLens))) var
    putStrLn $ show value 
    setM ((debug mvarLens) . (debug (liftLensM boxLens))) (Box 5) var
    output var 

    where
        output = \v -> (readMVar v) >>= (putStrLn . show)

-- Types to write higher lenses easily

type LensF f s t a b = Lens (f s) (f t) (f a) (f b)

type LensF' f s a = Lens' (f s) (f a)

type GetterF f s a = Getter (f s) (f a)

type SetterF f s t a b = Setter (f s) (f t) (f a) (f b) 

-- Lenses for MVars

setMVar :: IO (MVar a) -> IO a -> IO (MVar a)
setMVar ioVar ioValue = do
    var <- ioVar
    value <- ioValue
    swapMVar var value
    return var

getMVar :: IO (MVar a) -> IO a
getMVar ioVar = do
    var <- ioVar
    readMVar var
-- (flip (>>=)) readMVar 

mvarLens :: LensF' IO (MVar a) a
mvarLens = lens getMVar setMVar       

-- Lift a Lens' to a Lens' on monadic values           

liftLensM :: (Monad m) => Lens' s a -> LensF' m s a
liftLensM pureLens = lens getM setM
    where
        getM mS = do
            s <- mS
            return (s^.pureLens)
        setM mS mValue = do
            s <- mS
            value <- mValue
            return (set pureLens value s)


-- Output when a Lens' is used in IO 

debug :: (Show a) => LensF' IO s a -> LensF' IO s a 
debug l = lens debugGet debugSet
    where
        debugGet ioS = do
            value <- ioS^.l
            putStrLn $ show $ "Getting " ++ (show value)
            return value
        debugSet ioS ioValue = do
            value <- ioValue
            putStrLn $ show $ "Setting " ++ (show value)
            set l (return value) ioS

-- Easier way to use lenses in a monad (if you don't like writing return for each argument)

readM :: (Monad m) => GetterF m s a -> s -> m a
readM l s = (return s) ^. l

setM :: (Monad m) => SetterF m s t a b -> b -> s -> m t
setM l b s = set l (return b) (return s)

-- Another example lens

newtype Boxed a = Box {
    unBox :: a
} deriving Show

boxLens :: Lens' a (Boxed a) 
boxLens = lens Box (\_ -> unBox)
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Ordinary MVar
1
2

MVar accessed through a LensF' IO
2
3

MVar accessed through a LensF' IO that also debugs
"Getting 3"
3
"Setting 4"
4

MVar accessed through a LensF' IO that also debugs through a Box that's been lifted to LensF' IO that also debugs
"Getting 4"
"Getting Box {unBox = 4}"
Box {unBox = 4}
"Setting Box {unBox = 5}"
"Getting 4"
"Setting 5"
5
```

There's probably a better way to write `liftLensM` without resorting to using `lens`, `(^.)`, `set` and `do` notation. Something seems wrong about building lenses by extracting the getter and setter and calling `lens` on a new getter and setter.

I wasn't able to figure out how to reuse a lens as both a getter and a setter. `readM (debug mvarLens)` and `setM (debug mvarLens)` both work just fine, but any construct like 'let debugMVarLens = debug mvarLens' loses either the fact it works as a `Getter`, the fact it works as a `Setter`, or the knowledge that `Int` is an instance of `show` so it can me used for `debug`. I'd love to see a better way of writing this part.

Comment: What's the down vote for?  Down voting is not a substitute for communication.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried the methods in Petr and Cirdec's answers but never got to the point I wanted to. Started working on the problem, and at the end, I published the [references library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/references-0.1.0.0) on hackage with a generalization of lenses.

I followed the idea of the [yall](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yall) library to parameterize the references with monad types. As a result there is an `mvar` reference in `Control.Reference.Predefined`. It is an IO reference, so an access to the referenced value is done in an IO action.

There are also other applications of this library, it is not restricted to IO. An additional feature is to add references (so adding `_1` and `_2` tuple accessors will give a `both` traversal, that accesses both fields). It can also be used to release resources after accessing them, so it can be used to manipulate files safely.

The usage is like this:

```
test = 
  do result <- newEmptyMVar
     terminator <- newEmptyMVar
     forkIO $ (result ^? mvar) >>= print >> (mvar .= ()) terminator >> return ()
     hello <- newMVar (Just "World")
     forkIO $ ((mvar & just & _tail & _tail) %~= ('_':) $ hello) >> return ()
     forkIO $ ((mvar & just & element 1) .= 'u' $ hello) >> return ()
     forkIO $ ((mvar & just) %~= ("Hello" ++) $ hello) >> return ()

     x <- runMaybeT $ hello ^? (mvar & just) 
     mvar .= x $ result
     terminator ^? mvar
```

The operator `&` combines lenses, `^?` is generalized to handle references of any monad, not just a referenced value that may not exist. The `%~=` operator is an update of a monadic reference with a pure function.