# How to combine lenses in "parallel"

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm new to the excelent `Control.Lens` and I'm trying to combine 2 lens in "parallel" (not in sequence) like I would do with `Control.Arrow.&&&).

If I take the example from the `lens` documentation:

```
`data Foo a = Foo { _baz :: Int, _bar :: Int, a }
```

I would like to be able to do stuff like :

```
>> let foo = (bar &&& baz) .~ (1, 20) $ Foo undefined undefined "FOO"
>> foo ^. (bar &&& baz) 
(1, 20)
```

I've looked everywhere and I could not find a way to do so. Is that because :

- (&&&) exist with another name and I missed it.
- It's useless. I should not need it, therefore nobody bothered implementing it.
- It's trivial to do in another way (using `both` or `<*>`)

### Update

`&&&` can be implemented that way :

```
(/|\) :: Lens' f a -> Lens' f b -> Lens' f (a, b)
a /|\ b = lens getBoth setBoth where
    getBoth f = (f ^. a, f ^. b)
    setBoth f (v, w) = a .~ v $ f' where
        f' = b .~ w $ f

barz :: Lens' Foo (Int, Int)
barz = bar /|\ baz
```

However, it needs a type signature which is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just stumbled over this actual function, [as it is defined in `lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16/docs/src/Control-Lens-Unsound.html#lensProduct) (with a fat comment about the unsoundness right in the module name: `Control.Lens.Unsound`)

```
-- | A lens product. There is no law-abiding way to do this in general.
-- Result is only a valid 'Lens' if the input lenses project disjoint parts of 
-- the structure @s@. Otherwise "you get what you put in" law
--
-- @
-- 'Control.Lens.Getter.view' l ('Control.Lens.Setter.set' l v s) ≡ v
-- @
--
-- is violated by
--
-- >>> let badLens :: Lens' (Int, Char) (Int, Int); badLens = lensProduct _1 _1
-- >>> view badLens (set badLens (1,2) (3,'x'))
-- (2,2)
--
-- but we should get @(1,2)@.
--
-- Are you looking for 'Control.Lens.Lens.alongside'?
--
lensProduct :: ALens' s a -> ALens' s b -> Lens' s (a, b)
lensProduct l1 l2 f s =
    f (s ^# l1, s ^# l2) <&> \(a, b) -> s & l1 #~ a & l2 #~ b
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really have the time to look at it, but what is 'alonside' ?

Comment: [`alongside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:alongside) composes two lenses on _different_ structures to a lens on a tuple of structures, i.e. it's analogous to `***` in the same way `lensProduct` attempts to be analogous to `&&&`.

Answer (score 7):

This combinator is probably impossible to implement. Consider:

```
> (baz &&& baz) .~ (1,5)
```

What should this do?

Even a weaker for of the combinator:

```
(/|\) :: Lens' s a -> Lens' s a -> Traversal' s a
a /|\ b = (a &&& b) . both
```

would break the laws:

For example, let's look at `baz /|\ baz`. Since a `Traversal` is also a `Setter`, it must also satisfy the [`Setter` laws](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#t%3aSetter). Now, take the second setter law:

```
over (baz /|\ baz) (f . g) = over (baz /|\ baz) f . over (baz /|\ baz) g
```

Now, we get:

```
over (baz /|\ baz) (f . g) 
= \(Foo _baz _bar) -> Foo (f . g . f . g $ _baz) _bar
```

and:

```
over (baz /|\ baz) f . over (baz /|\ baz) g
= \(Foo _baz _bar) -> Foo (f . f . g . g $ _baz) _bar
```

Those two are obviously different. The problem arises when the two lenses "overlap", and this is not encoded in the type.

Comment: Minor typo: in the second setter law, `l` should be `f`. (BTW, "edits must be at least 6 characters" is quite annoying)

Comment: @bennofs: Yes `a &&& a` breaks the lens laws but how is it relevant ? `bar &&& baz` doesn't, which is what matters. I can find parameters (a,b) so that `lens a b` breaks  lens laws. That doesn't stop the `lens` function to be valid function. Moreover `&&&` can be implemented and seems to work (see update)

Answer (score 1):

As an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24910219/2604197) to another question, I propose a [library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/references) that is more general than the lens library. Among additional features, references can be combined "in parallel".

Of course it can raise interesting issues. For example `twice = self &+& self` is a reference that accesses itself twice:

```
 a ^* twice == [a,a]
 (twice *= x) a == x
 (twice *- f) a == f (f a)
```

(Do not be disturbed by the different operators. `^*` is similar to `^..`, `*=` is similar to `.~` and `*-` is similar to `%~` in [Control.Lens.Operators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html))