# Applying functions that depend on multiple fields using the lens

Tags: haskell, types, haskell-lens

Let `A, B, C` be types and there are two functions `f :: (A , B) -> A` and `g :: (A , B) -> B`. Consider following record type

`data Rec = Rec{_a :: A, _b :: B, _c :: C}`.

What would be the most elegant way to define function that maps `(Rec a b c)` to `(Rec (f a b) (g a b) c)` using the `lens` combinators?

Comment: Why does it need to be lens combinators specifically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Lenses

The lenses `a`, `b`, and `c` would be written out by hand in terms of `fmap` ([`<&>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-60--38--62-) is infix flipped fmap) as

```
a :: Functor f => (A -> f A) -> Rec -> f Rec
a f (Rec a b c) = f a <&> \a' -> Rec a' b c

b :: Functor f => (B -> f B) -> Rec -> f Rec
b f (Rec a b c) = f b <&> \b' -> Rec a b' c

c :: Functor f => (C -> f C) -> Rec -> f Rec
c f (Rec a b c) = f c <&> \c' -> Rec a b c'
```

As cchalmers points out, we can extend this pattern to write a lens for both the `_a` and `_b` fields at the same time

```
ab :: Functor f => ((A, B) -> f (A, B)) -> Rec -> f Ref
ab f (Rec a b c) = f (a,b) <&> \(a',b') -> Rec a' b' c
```

Combined with `&&&` from [`Control.Arrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Arrow.html) and [`%~`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:-37--126-) we can write the desired function elegantly as

```
inAB :: ((A, B) -> A) -> ((A, B) -> B) -> Rec -> Rec
inAB f g = ab %~ (f &&& g)
```

If you are very comfortable with the lens library you might prefer to use `(ab %~ (f &&& g))` instead of `inAB f g`.

There [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23322201/414413) a [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) function for building the lens `ab` from the lenses `a` and `b` since in general the product of two lenses onto the same underlying structure is not a lens for the product onto the one underlying structure; both of the two lenses might try to change the same underlying field and violate the lens laws.

#### No lenses

Without lenses, you can define a function to apply a function to the `_a` and `_b`  fields of the record.

```
onAB :: (A -> B -> c) -> Rec -> c
onAB f r = f (_a r) (_b r)
```

A function that modifies both the `_a` and `_b` fields based on a function for each just sets `_a` and `_b` to the results of the two functions applied to the fields.

```
inAB' :: (A -> B -> A) -> (A -> B -> B) -> Rec -> Rec
inAB' f g r = r {_a = onAB f r, _b = onAB g r}
```

Tossing in a couple `curry`s we get exactly the type signature you want

```
inAB :: ((A, B) -> A) -> ((A, B) -> B) -> Rec -> Rec
inAB f g = inAB' (curry f) (curry g)
```

#### Slower, less elegant lenses

With lenses we can also say that we are `set`ing `a` and `b`. It's not any more elegant than using the record constructor and it will need to construct the record twice.

```
inAB' :: (A -> B -> A) -> (A -> B -> B) -> Rec -> Rec
inAB' f g r = set b (onAB g r) . set a (onAB f r) $ r
```

Comment: Two questions discussing the problem you mention at the end: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17528119 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/23321844 . In this specific case the relevant lens is legal, and so in principle it would be fine to define it from scratch, though it probably wouldn't be worth the trouble.

Comment: Manually writing it isn't that bad: `_ab f (Rec a b c) = f (a,b) <&> \(a',b') -> Rec a' b' c`. Then the function is simply `_ab %~ \(a,b) -> (f a b, g a b)`.

Comment: @cchalmers It isn't indeed; my "not worth the trouble" was only relative to the lens-less solution, and assuming the composed lens won't prove useful elsewhere.